# Switch in Custom Listview

Tags: android, database, listview, switch-statement, android-cursoradapter

I am populating a ListView via `CursorAdapter` from SQLite Database Layout contained Switch.

How can I listen to the Switch change event for a particular ListItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Register a callback to be invoked when the checked state of this button changes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener)).

Example:

```
mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);
// attach a listener to check for changes in a state
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
    boolean isChecked) {
    // do something on event
 }
});
```

Also check [viewholder pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html).

Comment: New in JAVA can i have example